# Manipulation dom after using jsrender

Tags: jquery, jsrender, jquery-ui-button

Im my project I use `jsrender`. 
Below my example of code.

```
<script id="usersTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
<button id="createUser">Create</button>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>Name</td>
</tr>
{{for users tmpl="userRow" /}}
</table>
</script>
<script id="userRow">
<tr>
    <td>{{:id:}}</td>
    <td id="user{{:id}}">{{:name}}</td>
</tr>
</script>
```

After rendering I have no access to `$("#createUser")`
How can I do it? And how can I use jqueryui button for `$("#createUser")` after rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use jQuery in the usual way, such as in this example: http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/helpers

```
$("#movieList").on("click", "#sortBtn", myHandler);

var html = $("#movieTemplate").render(movies);

$("#movieList").html(html);
```

By using

`$("#movieList").on("click", "#sortBtn", myHandler);`

rather than

`$("#sortBtn").on("click", myHandler);`

you can bind the event before rendering.

But this will also work fine:

```
var html = $("#movieTemplate").render(movies);

$("#movieList").html(html);

$("#sortBtn").on("click", myHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved my problem early using  code like your code.
But i write $("#sortBtn").click(myhandler);